# calculus area problem

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac1{2x-1}$.

For every $p>1/2$, there is a rectangle with vertices $(0,0), (p,0), (p,f(p)),$ and $(0,f(p))$ with area $A(p)=p/(2p-1)$. For certain values of $a$ and $b$, $A(p)=a+b(f(p))$. Find $a$ and $b$.

I found $f(p)$ and tried plugging in, but failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated and will cut down on my Nexium and Xanax bills.

Comment: What is $b(f(p))$? Is $b$ a function? Or is $b(f(p))=b\times f(p)$?

Comment: b x f(p). Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
a+bf(p)={2ap+b-a\over2p-1}
$$
Compare this with 
$$
A(p)={p\over2p-1}
$$
What values of $a$ and $b$ make the right hand sides equal?

Comment: So I get p = 2ap + b - a.  Now what am I missing?

Comment: That you want $a$ and $b$ to be constant not depending on $p$. In other words, they are just numbers.

Comment: a=1/2 and b=1/2, but I don't see the clear way to derive them.

Comment: The "clear way" is based on the fact that two polynomials in $p$ are equal iff the coefficients of terms of the same power in $p$ are equal. So $2a=1$ and $b-a=0$.